# Random returns same value in for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, visual-c++, vector, random

I have reduced my code to be minimal and it compiles reproducing the same error. I know it puts out warnings, you don't need to mention them. I am pretty new to coding, so I appreciate the help.
    The problem I have is that the vectors Xpos and Ypos are returning the same value for each completion of the for loop in main(). I am getting a rnadom output, but all vector values are repeated. They should be different. Can you help me find what's wrong? Thank you so much. Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


//error is here?

int phaseTwoSimulate(double &Xpos, double &Ypos, int diameter, double stepSize) {


    while (pow(Xpos - 201, 2) + pow(Ypos - 201, 2) < pow(diameter, 2)) { 
// while inside cicle

        int direction = rand() % 4;
        switch (direction) {
        case 0://north
            Ypos = Ypos - stepSize;
            break;
        case 1://east
            Xpos = Xpos + stepSize;
            break;
        case 2://south
            Ypos = Ypos + stepSize;
            break;
        case 3://west
            Xpos = Xpos - stepSize;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    double Xpos = 201;
    double Ypos = 201;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
        phaseTwoSimulate(Xpos,Ypos,50,1);
        cout << Xpos << "," << Ypos << endl;
        double Xpos = 201;
        double Ypos = 201;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: That's what I did! Am I not understanding something about how to do it?

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Please reduce it to bare minimal to reproduce just the issue. And no, there's no need to post the whole program's code here unless asked for.

Comment: this is the minimum to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I spent a lot of time making it the minimum, and apparently it's not good enough.

Comment: How can this be the minimum when you told us to *"ignor this overload operator cout"*?

Comment: because you need to overload the operator << to cout the error in my data. It won't compile without it.

Comment: I could have used a for loop, I suppose, but this was easier.

Comment: Everyone is downvoting my question, again, I don't understand how to make this more minimal and still compile.

Comment: Paul as you can see there is a lot of code in your question. I doubt all of it is needed to display the problem. But that aside you can just store rand() values in a temp value before you use them, and cout that temp value so you can see where the problem is. In other words you will see rand() is return#ing you different values...

Comment: You redefine xpos and ypos in the loop.

Comment: also your code seems to work fine for me? are you sure you are not using some online compiler that caches the output of the program?

Comment: Well, I made it smaller and it's reproducing the error, do I need to try to make it smaller still?

Comment: Looks OK to me. So what output are you getting, and why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: The values should be different each time it goes through the for loop in main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the two lines in the middle of this code:

```
    cout << Xpos << "," << Ypos << endl;
    double Xpos = 201;
    double Ypos = 201;
}
```

What this is doing is declaring two **new** variables `Xpos` and `Ypos` and setting them to 201. These variables are not used. When your loop goes around again the next call to `phaseTwoSimulate` uses the old variables (and the old values) of `Xpos` and `Ypos`, which means that the point is already outside your circle and your loop in the function stops immediately.

To fix this, simple change it to:

```
    cout << Xpos << "," << Ypos << endl;
    Xpos = 201;
    Ypos = 201;
}
```

Or better yet, move the variables closer to where they are being used and change your code to be

```
int main()
{
    vector <int> vectorX;
    vector <int> vectorY;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
        double Xpos = 201;
        double Ypos = 201;
        phaseTwoSimulate(Xpos, Ypos, 50, 1);
        cout << Xpos << "," << Ypos << endl;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course it was something stupid that I should have seen, I am such a noob, thanks a lot!